# How to prevent EditText error icon from being pushed by padding?

Tags: android, error-handling, android-edittext

I am using the setError method of the EditText view. The problem is, I want the EditText text to only be filled up to a certain point, so I need to put a padding on it's right side. But then the error icon is also pushed by the padding. Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out there's no workaround for this. I just changed the logic of my custom edittext to add padding ONLY if the error icon is not shown

Comment: How much padding you have to add, i also have this problem with checkbox with setError.